# Using a lambda expression to specify parameter of method

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, methodinfo

Given the `MethodInfo` of a method how can I use a lambda expression to specify a parameter (`ParameterInfo`)?

For example, given the following method signature:

```
public string DoSomething(int id, int count);
```

I would like to have a method:

```
WithParameter(MethodInfo info, Expression<???> expression);
```

Which would be invoked like so:

```
WithParameter(doSomethingMethodInfo, x => x.id)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? There might be an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specify the parameter name in statically safe way, this is not possible.
Two reasons:

1. C# does not generally support this for parameters
2. `MethodInfo` had already lost all static type information

Alternative approaches are different depending on your final goal.